# Firebase User Inbox using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an inbox for users in my app. I am however having a problem reloading the tableView. If I remove `self.tabelView.reloadData()` The app view runs fine, but of course won't update the table cells. The query does make it because I can print the result array out. The eror I get is a LLDB error. It states "EXC_BreakPoint", I did not set any break points. Here is my code:

```
class InboxTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var pinggedUser: String!

var toBeUserId: String!


let dataBase = FIRDatabase.database()

var SecondResultArray: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []



override func viewDidLoad() {



      messageReference = rootReference.child("messages")

    //let UserRef = messageReference.child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName)!)

    messageReference.queryOrderedByChild("senderName")
        .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock:{ snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {


                self.SecondResultArray.append(child as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                //print(self.ResultArray)


            }

            print(self.SecondResultArray )

                self.tableView.reloadData()


        })


    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return SecondResultArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("inboxCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    let inBox: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.SecondResultArray[indexPath.row]

    let book = inBox.value as! Dictionary<String, String>



    let receiver = book["receiver"] as String!

    let senderId = book["senderId"] as String!

    let messageText = book["text"] as String!


    let senderName = book["senderName"] as String!


    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping



    cell.textLabel?.text = "Your Messages With:" + "" + senderName


    return cell
}


 }
```

Comment: what is your exact problem EXC_BreakPoint or tablecell wont be update?

Comment: I actually don't know if the table will update or not, because of that error. So I will say that the error is my main problem. It occurs when self.tableView.reloadData is called in viewDidLoad. When I call it any where else there is no error, but then the table does not load the data.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you did not Register your tableview.

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Comment: where would I do that? In viewDidLoad?

Comment: Same error and did not work. I suspect that it has something to with being inside the FirebaseQuery, but if I call it outside of the query it doesn't reload the table either.

Comment: are you getting values in array?

Comment: Yes, I used a print statement and it shows that I am getting values in the array.

Comment: you just print this array to out of your block then tell me it is print or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116751/discussion-between-kalpesh-and-taylor-simpson).

Comment: It does, I had it print in the cellForRowAtIdexPath Method and it prints there too.